# Any easy or shorter way of going through list in jquery?

Tags: jquery, list, class

Basically, i have 4 list. Whichever list is clicked, i want to add a class, if other list where clicked, i want to remove the class from other list. just want to apply it to the one have been clicked.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#li1").click(function(){
            document.getElementById('li1').classList.add('focus');
            document.getElementById('li2').classList.remove('focus');
            document.getElementById('li3').classList.remove('focus');
            document.getElementById('li4').classList.remove('focus');
      });

      $("#li2").click(function(){
            document.getElementById('li2').classList.add('focus')
            document.getElementById('li1').classList.remove('focus');
            document.getElementById('li3').classList.remove('focus');
            document.getElementById('li4').classList.remove('focus');   
      });

      $("#li3").click(function(){
            document.getElementById('li3').classList.add('focus')
            document.getElementById('li1').classList.remove('focus');
            document.getElementById('li2').classList.remove('focus');
            document.getElementById('li4').classList.remove('focus');   
      });

      $("#li4").click(function(){
            document.getElementById('li4').classList.add('focus')
            document.getElementById('li1').classList.remove('focus');
            document.getElementById('li2').classList.remove('focus');
            document.getElementById('li3').classList.remove('focus');   
      });


    });
</script>


    ---HTML----
    <ul>
         <li id="li1"> some text here </li>
         <li id="li2"> some text here </li>
         <li id="li3"> some text here </li>
         <li id="li4"> some text here </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Post your HTML please. And why are you doing things like `document.getElementById('li4').classList.add('focus')` if you're using jQuery when you can do `$('#li4').addClass('focus')`?

Comment: I have updated my post and added the HTML, it's just a basic UL. 
Please bear with me, I'm newbie with javascript / jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li').click(function(event){
  $('li').removeClass('focus');
  $(event.target).addClass('focus');
})
```

This removes all 'focus' classes and then adds it to the clicked li.

More reading:
http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your markup:

```
var $lists = $('[id^="li"]');

$lists.click(function(){
  $lists.removeClass('focus');
  $(this).addClass('focus');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akPF5/3/))

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li class='current'>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
    <li class='current'>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

**JS::**

```
$('#list1 > li').add('#list2 > li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

**Or, maybe this one** ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akPF5/4/))

```
$('#list1 > li').add('#list2 > li').on('click', function(){
    $('ul[id^="list"] > li').siblings().removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```